# GetBlob() method not recognized even after importing oracle.sql.blob

Tags: eclipse, oracle, blob, java

I have a .Java file in an Application where the code which like this

```
blob = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB("Document");
```

I have imported oracle.sql.blob. `import Oracle.sql.BLOB`

But even after that I am having complier error and intellisense suggesting me to `Create method 'getBLOB(string)' in type OracleResultSet`

Is this a problem because of JRE system library? I checked it too... the Jar file is properly added.

Just another point this problem is happening after a fresh installation of Eclipse. Do I need to add any additional JAR or perform some configuration?

Comment: I have upgraded the JDK version of my machine to JDK 7 and it did the trick. The JRE system library files were not all available with the previous version. No this sort of issues anymore.

Answer (score 0):

the method signature should be

```
Blob getBlob(String columnLabel) throws SQLException
```

so, try writing the last three letters in lower case:

```
blob = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBlob("Document");
```

Comment: Tried that but it din't work. Thanks any way...It used to work beforehad but after a fresh installation of Eclipse I am encountering this. Is there any where I could go wrong with the installation?

Comment: Ignore my first answer. Oracle actually writes BLOB in uppercase. You asked if you need some additional JAR-file, do you have the Oracle JDBC (ie ojdbc6.jar) added to your build path? I'm trying to recreate this problem, but if I remove the ojdbc file it shows different errors.

Comment: in case you have that JAR added, does a right click -> open declaration on your imports (i.e. `import Oracle.sql.BLOB`) actually lead you to the correct jar?

Comment: Yes `Oracle.sql.BLOB` is already imported...so probably it is not related to Jar.. I am trying to reinstall Eclipse today..probably the last instalaltion has gone wrong. As I said this worked in other machines..but in the new machine after Eclipse installation I am unable to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded the JDK version of my machine to JDK 7 and it did the trick. The JRE system library files were not all available with the previous version. No this sort of issues anymore.